# multiprocessing.pool() hangs indefinitely

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool

I'm trying to get my program to process data faster by using `multiprocessing.Pool`, but I'm getting some problems implementing it.

My program has a main file in which I have a tkinter GUI running, something like this:

```
WIDTH = 1345
HEIGHT = 665 
root = tk.Tk()

Calculate(Config, matrices):
    (Calls the function Manager(), which is stored in another .py)

def main():
    --variables, bindings and stuff--
    btncalc.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: Calculate(Config=Config,matrices=matrices))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and then, if the user clicks on the button, the function `Calculate` calls a function that manages the data processing, and is stored in another .py. This is where I use `multiprocessing.Pool`. The code on the other file is similar to this:

```
def worker(lista):
    a,b,c,d,e = lista
    (processing)
    return [f,g,h,i]

def MultiprocessingFunc(a,b,c,d,e):
    lista = []
    results = []
    
    for p in range(len(a)):
        lista.append([a[p],b,c,d,e])
 
    pool = Pool(os.cpu_count()) #in my case this is 4
    results.append(pool.map(worker, lista)) #Hangs here sometimes
    pool.close() 
    pool.join() #Hangs here if imap
    return results

def Manager(Config, matrices):
    (prepares stuff)
    results = MultiprocessingFunc(a,b,c,d,e)
    (uses the results)
```

The fun thing about this is that sometimes this code does work, and sometimes it just hangs on `pool.map`. I don't know why it keeps hanging sometimes, but sometimes it does work fine. Maybe I should be using `Process` and `Queue` instead of `Pool`? Since it just hangs indefinitely, there are no error messages, so I don't know where to start to debug the code. I don't know if it matters, but I'm using Python3.8.

Comment: How does `tkinter` fit into all this? That could very well be key because it doesn't support multiprocessing or multithreading.

Comment: Yes, forget tk for now, write a minimal multiprocessing script and debug that. Then connect it to your button. But some things you can try: 1) create the pool in your main function and pass it as an argument, 2) don’t block tk’s event loop, dispatch the button call to a thread